# Joining table and subquery in jpa

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have two tables T1 and T2 where t2 is result of subquery

to make it clear

```
select * from T1 join (select * from T3 where foo is not null) T2 on T1.key = T2.fk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1 FROM Table1Entity T1 JOIN Table1Entity.table2EntityAssociationField T2 WHERE T2.foo IS NOT NULL
```

where

```
@Entity
class Table1Entity {

      @OneToOne
      Table2Entity table2EntityAssociationField;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Table2Entity {

     private Object foo;

}
```

Comment: Thx, but now i need to have the same for outer join

Comment: I don't understand, doesn't it suffice to replace JOIN with OUTER JOIN in the above?

Comment: Take a look at the generated SQL when your slow query is executed, see if it doesn't generate some crappy SQL (n+1 selects, etc) there.

Comment: thing is in my query first i'm doing selection and then join, so i'm no doing not nessesery joins